# Create tar.gz using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gzip, tar

I am new to .NET. Is it possible to create a tar.gz using a .NET environment? If yes, how?

Comment: I am not sure but look for SharpZipLib website for more whether they support it or not.

Comment: #ziplib (SharpZipLib, formerly NZipLib) is a Zip, GZip, Tar and BZip2 library written entirely in C# for the .NET platform. Yes it supports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you can also use 
http://sevenziplib.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Amit So what? 7-Zip is able to handle that

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at SharpZipLib

http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Create a tar archive using a suitable library, say http://code.google.com/p/tar-cs/.
2. Then compress the tar using [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class.

Of course, you should be familiar with streams.