# Read tgz archived file without saving/extracting to disk

Tags: c#

I've been searching for a solution for reading one or more files from a .tgz or .tar.gz archive using C#, without having to extract the files to disk.

I've identified a number of third party libs published under GNU licenses that allow someone to extract a .tgz archive but haven't had any luck locating a solution to read the file without extracting it first .

If possible, I'd like to stick to the standard libraries - does anyone have a solution using GZipStream or any other method/s? Thanks!

EDIT:

I would like to implement something similar to the following:

```
public static void Decompress2(FileInfo fileToDecompress)
{
    using (FileStream fileStream = fileToDecompress.OpenRead())
    {
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            string currentFileName = fileToDecompress.FullName;
            string newFileName = currentFileName.Remove(currentFileName.Length - fileToDecompress.Extension.Length);

            using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create(newFileName))
            {
                using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
                    int n;
                    while ((n = decompressionStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        memStream.Write(bytes, 0, n);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Were the file is extracted from the .tgz or .tar.gz archive and loaded into memory. Once extracted to memory, I need to be able to read the contents of the extracted file. The provided code should allow me to extract a .gz but I'm not sure how to add support for .tar or how to read the file once its been loaded into memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [tar.gz using .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212118/tar-gz-using-net).

Comment: Any way to to this w/o using SharpZipLib and/or w/o saving to disk first? I really want to avoid any third partly libs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have just implemented ([blog post](http://brunov.info/blog/2013/10/06/extract-tar-gz-archives-with-tar-cs-library/)) tar.gz-archive extraction example using [tar-cs library](https://code.google.com/p/tar-cs/) which is under [New BSD License](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause). The example demonstrates how to extract the content of tar.gz-archive to disk.

```
/// <summary>
/// Example of tar-cs library usage to extract tar.gz-archives.
/// Please use the latest version (from trunk) of the library.
/// </summary>
public static class TarGZip
{
    public static void Extract(string inputFile, string outputDirectory)
    {
        using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
        using (Stream tarStream = UnGZipSteam(inputStream))
        {
            var tarReader = new TarReader(tarStream);
            while (tarReader.MoveNext(false)) // Moves pointer to the next file in the tar archive.
            {
                ExtractTarEntry(tarReader, outputDirectory);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Since GZipStream.Position Property is not implemented,
    /// it is necessary to use MemoryStream as intermediate storage.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputStream">The input stream.</param>
    /// <returns>Un-gzipped stream.</returns>
    private static Stream UnGZipSteam(Stream inputStream)
    {
        using (GZipStream gZipStream = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            gZipStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            return memoryStream;
        }
    }

    private static void ExtractTarEntry(TarReader tarReader, string outputDirectory)
    {
        string relativePath = tarReader.FileInfo.FileName;

        // Relative path can contain slash, not backslash.
        // Use Path.GetFullPath() method to convert path.
        string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(outputDirectory, relativePath));

        switch (tarReader.FileInfo.EntryType)
        {
            case EntryType.File:
            case EntryType.FileObsolete:
                using (FileStream outputStream = File.Create(fullPath))
                {
                    // Read data from a current file to a Stream.
                    tarReader.Read(outputStream);
                }
                break;
            case EntryType.Directory:
                Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException("Not supported entry type: " + tarReader.FileInfo.EntryType);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that since [GZipStream.Position Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.position.aspx) is not implemented, it is necessary to use MemoryStream as intermediate storage or implement `GZipStream` wrapper with `Position` property support.